# Can't send with ajax in zend framework 3

Tags: ajax, zend-framework3

I'm trying to send a ajax to call my function 'alterarPermissoesAction' in GrupoUsuarioController.

js code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?= $this->url( 'grupo-usuario-insumo', [ 'action' => 'alterarPermissoes' ] ) ?>',
    data: dados,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( r ) {
        console.log( r );
    }
});
```

When I do this, zf3 try to render a page and send me that page as response.

[return image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFC99.png)

What should I do to zf3 stop trying render a page?

Comment: How does your controller action look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a data response, you should make sure to use a different `ViewHelper` by way of the `ViewJsonStrategy`. Add the following to your modules' config.

```
'view_manager' => [
    'strategies' => [
        'ViewJsonStrategy', // This is an alias, so add as string
    ],
],
```

Next up, you have an action in your controller that must know it must return Json. You do this with the `JsonModel`. [Example in a good book](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Model_View_Controller/View_Rendering_Strategies.html) - example code below (from link):

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class IndexController extends ActionController
{
    public function getJsonAction()
    {
        return new JsonModel([
            'status' => 'SUCCESS',
            'message'=>'Here is your data',
            'data' => [
                'full_name' => 'John Doe',
                'address' => '51 Middle st.'
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to use this conditionally, e.g. with dynamic form responses without a page refresh, you want to check whether or not the request is an `XmlHttpRequest`, like so:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class IndexController extends ActionController
{
    public function getJsonAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

            return new JsonModel([
                'status' => 'SUCCESS',
                'message'=>'Here is your data',
                'data' => [
                    'full_name' => 'John Doe',
                    'address' => '51 Middle st.'
                ]
            ]);
        }

        return [
            'normal' => 'response',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I made a "quick fix" putting a die function in there to work, but now I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, the `alterarPermissoesAction` must end with :

```
return $this->getResponse()->setContent(
            Json::encode(
                [
                    [your response]
                ]));
```

But not to apply the layout you must specify in your `Module.php` something like :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    ...
    $sharedEvents = $e->getApplication()
        ->getEventManager()
        ->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', 
        function ($e) {
            $result = $e->getResult();
            if ($result instanceof \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel) {
                $result->setTerminal($e->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest());
            } else {
                throw new \Exception([your message]);
            }
        });
}
```